# MySQL Workbench: merging multiple rows into one row using same call_ID

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

The data is like:

```
CallID | callin | callout

 456   |  16267777 | *123

   456 | *123      |19095351

  789  | 1323789   |  *123

   789 |  *123     |180515978
```

(*123 is the system extension number )

Table name : call_history

Now I want to regroup the data to become:

```
 CallID           callin           callout

 456             16267777         19095351

 789             1323789          180515978
```

How do I do it ? By using Selfjoin? GROUP?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to permanently replace the current data or simply select consolidated rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inner join

```
select a.callID, a.callin, b.callout
from call_history as  a 
inner join call_history as b on a.callID = b.callID
where a.callin !='*123' 
and b.callout !='*123'
```